# Django Class Based View (FormView)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

```
class ReviewView(FormView):
    
    form_class = ReviewForm
    template_name = "review/review.html"
    success_url = "/thank-you"
   
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

this is the error
how can I fix it

AttributeError at /
'ReviewForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: Please add your `ReviewForm` to the question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Form`s don't have a `save()` method.

You need to use a `ModelForm` as that will then have a `model` associated with it and will know what to save where https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

If you don't need to save anything that is fine.